# To install Red5, what are the server requirements?

Tags: red5

I have this server detail:

```
System: CentOS 6.3
Size:   4096 MB RAM, 160 GB Disk
Type: virtual cloud server, it is hosted on a hypervisor physical machine.
```

And i am using red5 video recorder application. Its fine in my local but not smooth in the server.

Is it fine configuration to make video recorder application using red5?

Thanks

Comment: maybe the bandwith on your server is low

Comment: @fmodos what will be min bandwidth? http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/is-there-a-throughput-limit-on-my-servers-network-interface-card this shows me public and server limit bandwidth... look at the fifth row 4096MB 100 Mbps 200 Mbps is my bandwidth.. So what you say is it fine?